# Arguments type to send Magento SOAP V1 customer.create request from C#

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap

I'm creating an Magento iterface using C# and Magento SOAP V1 with call method but I don't find the way to send args to the function from c#. The function on PHP is the following:

```
$result = $client->customerCustomerCreate($session, array('email' => 'customer-mail@example.org', 'firstname' => 'Dough', 'lastname' => 'Deeks', 'password' => 'password', 'website_id' => 1, 'store_id' => 1, 'group_id' => 1));
```

Error:

> There was an error generating the XML document.
>             The type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary is not supported because it implements IDictionary.

I already tested the function customer.info sending simple value as argument as following and is working fine.

```
var custinfo = client.call(mlogin, "customer.info", "1");
```

Any Idea???